# Google Font CSS different when pulled via WGET

Tags: css, wget, google-webfonts

I'm trying to dynamically grab a Google Fonts css file so I can parse it for the font URL.  I'm hitting some odd behavior.  Compare:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans  (From Chrome, if it matters)

To

```
WGET -qO- http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans
```

From Chrome, I get:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Droid Sans'), local('DroidSans'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v3/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciBsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff') format('woff');
}
```

But WGET gives me:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Droid Sans'), local('DroidSans'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v3/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciC3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I see thirtydot's answer at [Google fonts external CSS Vs copying the code of external css in my css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203871/google-fonts-external-css-vs-copying-the-code-of-external-css-in-my-css) stating that Google serves up different CSS based on who is requesting the file.  Anyone know what WGET params I can pass so that it hands me the same version I am getting from Chrome?

Comment: use chrome's User-Agent string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.24 Safari/536.5" http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans
```

Comment: You, sir, are my new best friend.  Thank you!

Comment: I used it one month back, it was working. but now its not working. I'm getting 404. Surprisingly curl works.